# What is effect typing useful for when all global effects already have to be in the IO monad?

Tags: programming-languages, typing

[This paper](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/slindley/papers/handlers.pdf) adds effect handlers to a number of languages, including Haskell - and also adds a form of effect typing to Haskell. But what's the point of the latter? I know that effect types can be used in a metaprogramming context (e.g. in a compiler) to prove the soundness of optimisations, but are there any uses of effect typing outside metaprogramming in Haskell?